# Counter Strike (1.6/Source) Voice

Tags: counter-strike-source, voice-chat, counter-strike

Is there any way to play an MP3 via voice/TeamSpeak in Counter Strike? So not to send my own speech, but an MP3?

Comment: Depending on what you intend to play, be aware that such action might not be received well by other players on the server :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this over Counter Strike. This site has all the info you need: [HLSS](http://www.hlss.us/).

Here's a couple of guides:

[Counter-Strike 1.6](http://www.hlss.us/setuphlss/index.php?p=1)
[Counter-Strike: Source](http://www.hlss.us/setuphlss/index.php?p=15)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use [hlss](http://www.hlss.us).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a program called [HLDJ](http://www.hldj.org/)